# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting on Individual Cells

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I've tried searching low, high, and deep within the crevices of the internet to find a possible solution to this, but have had no luck. My main goal is to highlight **individual** cells based on a couple criteria. I have a google sheet that tracks jobs based on input from employees. My conditions are:

1. Date must be before today
2. Cell must be empty (no input from that day)
3. Only the cell that is empty should be highlighted

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10W9O55QQ31acOj5SyKcE0CXx8S78MZQtY-sRaIKgB7c/edit?usp=sharing

The goal of this is to make cells that did not receive any data stand out. The current formula I have is

```
=AND(ARRAYFORMULA(ISBLANK($B3:$D3)), ARRAYFORMULA(ISBLANK($I3:$K3)), $A3<TODAY())
```

But this is only highlighting the entire row, and when a cell in that row is filled, it no longer highlights that row. The yellow row is today's date. Any help in solving this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: A screenshot is not much help in this instance. If you'd like to share a sample spreadsheet, being sure when you create the link to set the permission to "Anyone with the link" and "Editor," I think your chances of receiving help will increase greatly.

Comment: Ok! I'll do that!

Comment: @Erik Original post edited to have example sheet rather than the screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not 100% clear what should be happening with the merged Column E:H. But from the limited data and assigned colors I see in your sheet, try swapping out your current "pink" custom CF rule with this one:

`=AND($A3<TODAY(), OR(AND(COLUMN(B3)<=4, B3=""), AND(COLUMN(B3)>=9, B3=""), AND(COLUMN(B3)>4, COLUMN(B3)<9, OR(B3<>"", JOIN("",$B3:$K3)=""))))`

Comment: The middle is just a separator and no data gets entered there except holidays

Comment: I assume, since you've marked this solution as "Best Answer," that it is functioning as you expected. If that is not the case, let me know specifically what should be different.

Answer (score 0):

#### You need to set a conditional format rule for *each column*

I believe here are the conditional format rules you need:

| Apply To Range | Formula |
| --- | --- |
| A3:A | `=AND(OR(ARRAYFORMULA(ISBLANK($B3:$D3)), ARRAYFORMULA(ISBLANK($I3:$K3))), $A3<TODAY())` **Note the OR* |
| B3:B | `=AND($A3<TODAY(), ISBLANK($B3))` |
| C3:C | `=AND($C3<TODAY(), ISBLANK($C3))` |
| D3:D | `=AND($D3<TODAY(), ISBLANK($D3))` |
| I3:I | `=AND($I3<TODAY(), ISBLANK($I3))` |
| J3:J | `=AND($J3<TODAY(), ISBLANK($J3))` |
| K3:K | `=AND($K3<TODAY(), ISBLANK($K3))` |

The key concept here is that within one rule you cannot specify specific ranges to apply the rule to. Part of the definition of the rule is the range that it applies to. You can have rules that take precedence over certain ranges, but you cannot have two ranges in one rule. You can *test* many ranges in one rule, but the formatting applies to the whole range the rule is applied to.

*Make sure you have deleted previous rules before applying these to make sure they don't take precedence*

#### Reference

- [Conditional Formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en#zippy=%2Cuse-custom-formulas-with-conditional-formatting)

Comment: This still seems to highlight only the row when it's entirely empty. once a cell is filled in that row, it no longer highlights it. I've edited the original post with a link to an example spreadsheet rather than a simple screenshot

Comment: Apologies, I must have misread. I have updated the answer, hopefully this does what you intend.

Comment: Not only does this work, but so does the other solution on this post! Glad to know there's more than one way to go about this!